# How can I remove Vue transition dynamically

Tags: vue.js, transition

I have a table body which is declared as animation block.

In some particular scenarios I want remove the transition to the table body. Is there any way to do that.

Answer (score 6):

#### HTML

```
<transition name="condition ? 'fade' : ''">
    <p>Hello</p>
</transition>
```

Specify the condition in the name attribute, when condition is true (or equal any value) run the "name" argument, in another case leave it empty and the transition will not work

Comment: Very clever thank you, this is WAY better than the current top answer.

Comment: but it doesn't disable the tag, so if you suddenly (on some condition) have more than one element inside there's still an error, which is not the case with the second answer

Comment: This still caused a flickering for me. My solution was to disable it via the `:css="true/false"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template with if-else condition:

```
<template v-if="condition">
  <transition> <!-- if condition matched, use transition -->
    <<html element>>
  </transition>
</template>
<template v-else>
   <<html element>>
</template>
```